# Help - Acces to phone taken over

Tags: internal-storage

I have an LG Stylo 2 or LG775 and people from my house are hacked into my phone please help me!

[image: Recently used Devices]
<sup>Click on Image to enlarge</sup>

Comment: What exactly are the pictures supposed to represent, are they not your devices? If not, go to mail.google.com (browser) and sign out all other sessions, change your Google account password, and turn on 2-step authentication. Problem solved.

Comment: The problem is they have my old phone and I changed my passwords plenty of times on Google and Facebook they keep getting back in and logging me out

Comment: Oh and the pic of the computer is not mine

Comment: Did you enable 2-step authentication? I don't know they could be logging in and changing anything without the verification code

Answer (score 0):

Change your password for your Google account and add another verification method onto your account.